# Sending ethereum smart contract transactions to miners

Tags: blockchain, mining, gas-price

We are building a decentralized document issuance application using the ethereum blockchain. For every transaction, some gas costs deduced in the form of ether.

Is it possible to host ethereum miner and then send it to that specific miner for mining so that gas cost be reduced?

Answer (score 3):

No. That isn't how it works.

It's a distributed network in which no node has a privileged position, so your idea is not possible. Unless I misunderstand the question, it would require your node to receive special treatment.

Gas cost for contract deployment is the price you pay to release persistent code into the network.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, nothing prevents you from running a miner which only takes for example transactions with zero gas price. Then you submit your tx with zero gas price and your miner node will pick it up. Then the node has to of course still solve the mining puzzle successfully.

This doesn't guarantee anything of course, as @Rob pointed out, but it's better than nothing - assuming you for reason really need such functionality. Although you most likely really don't need such.